# Motorola Symbol 3000 (CE 5) , achieve a CAB persistent Installation

Tags: mobile, persistence, windows-ce, motorola

as stated in the title my problem is how to achieve a persistent installation, starting from a cabinet file (over a Motorola Symbol 3000 device).

With the term persistent installation i mean a way to put extracted files, and to configure the device, so that installation can persist over a coold reboot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a problem if the CAB gets reinstalled after every *Cold Boot*?

If not, then:

> - Move your *CAB* file to the *"Application"* folder;
> - Create a *.reg* file with the content bellow;

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Symbol\Startup\Programs\Prog16]
"Name"="\Windows\wceload.exe"
"Command"="/noaskdest /delete 0 \Application\YOUR_CAB_NAME_HERE.cab"
"Continue"=dword:0
"ColdBootOnly"=dword:1
```

> - Copy the *.reg* file into your *"Application"* folder and run it from the device;
> - When prompted, click ***"YES"*** to confirm the merge;

That should do it

Comment: No, it is absolutely not a problem, i will try your solution as soon as possible, thanks in advance for help.